# TBMP skeleton - How do I override notification events

Tags: android, google-play-games, multiplayer

I am following the TBMP Skeleton app to create my own `TurnBased Multiplayer` game.

I tried using these methods to handle notifications but they are never called:

```
@Override
public void onInvitationReceived(Invitation invitation) {
    Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "An invitation has arrived from "
                    + invitation.getInviter().getDisplayName(), TOAST_DELAY)
            .show();
}

@Override
public void onTurnBasedMatchReceived(TurnBasedMatch match) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "A match was updated.", TOAST_DELAY).show();
}
```

Does anybody know why these methods aren't called when a player clicks on a game notification?

And alternatively, if these methods are never being called, how does `Google API` handle my receiving notifications?

My notification messages say instead: `Player1 invites you to a match of Skeleton Tbmp` and `It's your turn in a match of Tbmp Skeleton with Player1`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was missing these lines:

```
Games.Invitations.registerInvitationListener(getApiClient(), this);

Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.registerMatchUpdateListener(getApiClient(), this);
```

Answer (score 0):

(Just adding some detail to the existing answer here for future searchers)

You need to register an invitation/match update listener. See Games.Invitations.registerInvitationListener.

Note, though, that these listeners do not run when your game is not running. In that case, the user will get a system notification instead. This also means that if you do use these listeners in your game, no notification will appear in the system tray.